high power consumption in Ubuntu 24.04.1
Ubuntu has high power consumption even when ideal(after reboot ensuring no unchecked background apps).
Here is the output of sensors command
❯ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

pch_cometlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +56.0°C  

nvme-pci-3a00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +39.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +39.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3488 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 4900 RPM)
fan2:        3506 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 4900 RPM)
temp1:        +68.0°C  
temp2:        +54.0°C  
temp3:        +59.0°C  
temp4:        +52.0°C  
temp5:        +45.0°C  
temp6:        +65.0°C  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max =  +5.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          10.67 V  
curr1:         2.15 A

The curr1 value used to be about 350mA reaching 900mA when streaming YouTube.
Earlier I would fix this problem via 'dist-upgrade', but that isn't doing the job.
